# How To Sync CSS Animations Across Multiple Elements?

Tags: animation, webkit, css

I have two elements on a page that I'd like to animate via CSS (specifically, -webkit-animation). The animation itself simply bounces an element up and down. One element is always shown and bouncing, the other is not animated until mouse-over (hover).

My question is: Is it possible to sync (have both elements reach their apex at the same time, etc) the animation across both elements regardless of when the 2nd element's animation is started?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="bouncy01">Drip</div>
<div id="bouncy02">droP</div>
```

and my CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
    25% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);}
    75% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
#bouncy01,
#bouncy02 {
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#bouncy01 {
    -webkit-animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
#bouncy02 {
    background: #ffff00;
}
#bouncy02:hover {
    -webkit-animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

and finally, a working demo of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZLmq/2/

(to see the problem, mouse-over the yellow block)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I don't think its possible natively, but you can actually hack similar functionality by using a bouncing wrapper and some position altering

html:

```
<div id="bouncywrap">
    <div id="bouncy01">Drip</div>
    <div id="bouncy02">droP</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0% { padding-top:1px;}
/* using padding as it does not affect position:relative of sublinks
 * using 0 instead of 0 b/c of a box-model issue,
 * on kids wiht margin, but parents without margin, just try out
 */
    50% { padding-top:5px;} /*desired value +1*/
    100% { padding-top:1px;}
}

#bouncy01,
#bouncy02 {
    margin:10px;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    width:30px;
       position:absolute;
}
#bouncywrap {
    -webkit-animation:bounce 0.125s ease-in-out infinite;
    position:relative;
    width:140px;
    height:50px;
/*    background:grey; /*debug*/
}
#bouncy02 {
    background: #ffff00;
    left:60px;
    top:2px; /*half of desired value, just a fix for the optic*/
}
#bouncy02:hover {
    position:relative; /*here happens the magic*/
    top:0px;
}
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/A92pU/1/

Comment: Oh yeah... I forgot to mention that this approach wouldn't work in my case (my elements are on different sides of the page). Thanks though!

Comment: why not? An 0px high, empty, transparent div wont hurt design nor usability.

Comment: just like here http://jsfiddle.net/A92pU/2/, if you provide more details/show me the actual design i might help more

Comment: Looks very funny =)

Answer (score 18):

The [Web Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API) now allows to control animations very precisely and quite easily.

There are various ways to declare a Web Animation, but since here we started with CSS, here is how to hook to it:

```js
// when the animation starts
document.querySelector("#bouncy02")
  .addEventListener("animationstart", (evt) => {
  // double check it the animation we wanted
  if (evt.animationName === "bounce") {
    // retrieve both Animation objects
    const myAnim = findAnimByName(evt.target, "bounce");
    const otherAnim = findAnimByName(document.querySelector("#bouncy01"), "bounce");
    // update mine to act as if it started
    // at the same time as the first one
    myAnim.startTime = otherAnim.startTime;
  }
});
// simple helper to find an Animation by animationName
function findAnimByName(elem, name) {
  // get all the active animations on this element
  const anims = elem.getAnimations();
  // return the first one with the expected animationName
  return anims.find((anim) => anim.animationName === name);
}
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
    0% {transform: translateY(0px);}
    25% {transform: translateY(-2px);}
    50% {transform: translateY(-4px);}
    75% {transform: translateY(-2px);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
#bouncy01,
#bouncy02 {
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#bouncy01 {
    animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
#bouncy02 {
    background: #ffff00;
}
#bouncy02:hover {
    animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="bouncy01">Drip</div>
<div id="bouncy02">droP</div>
```

Note that while it's surprisingly not yet *that* propular, this API actually exists for some times now, and its [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/Animation#browser_compatibility) (all except IE) is quite good.

Note that if you don't need the first animation to start "from the beginning", and need to handle more than 2 elements, we can even simplify this code further by using a constant value for the `startTime` instead of retrieving the one from the running animation:

```js
// when the animation starts
document.querySelectorAll("div[id]").forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("animationstart", (evt) => {
    // double check it the animation we wanted
    if (evt.animationName === "bounce") {
      const myAnim = findAnimByName(evt.target, "bounce");
      myAnim.startTime = 0; // same origin for all animations
    }
   });
});
// simple helper to find an Animation by animationName
function findAnimByName(elem, name) {
  // get all the active animations on this element
  const anims = elem.getAnimations();
  // return the first one with the expected animationName
  return anims.find((anim) => anim.animationName === name);
}
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
    0% {transform: translateY(0px);}
    25% {transform: translateY(-2px);}
    50% {transform: translateY(-4px);}
    75% {transform: translateY(-2px);}
    100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
#bouncy01,
#bouncy02 {
    margin:10px;
    float: left;
    background: #ff0000;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
#bouncy01 {
    animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
#bouncy02 {
    background: #ffff00;
}
#bouncy02:hover {
    animation:bounce 0.25s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="bouncy01">Drip</div>
<div id="bouncy02">droP</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

I was looking for an alternative solution to those proposed here because:

1. I am animating a background color - which can't use the positioning magic in the accepted answer.
2. I wanted to avoid calculations for a very simple animation in my app.

After further research I came across [this module](https://github.com/bealearts/css-animation-sync) by [bealearts](http://bealearts.co.uk/).

It exposes a very neat API that lets you keep an animation in sync across the app by referring to it's name:

```js
import sync from 'css-animation-sync';
sync('spinner');
```

Since this seemed a little too good to be true, I tested the library (which is a single short file) in this fiddle and am happy to report [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/txe96dkg/1/) (hover on the third image and see that I quickly syncs to the second image's animation) :).

Credit: I used the animation from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/) by Simurai as a basis for my fiddle.

If anyone wants to replicate the mechanism behind this synchronisation, the code is open, but in it's essence, it uses events listeners for the animation itself as sync points:

```js
window.addEventListener('animationstart', animationStart, true);
window.addEventListener('animationiteration', animationIteration, true);
```

Hope this helps the next person looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: Nice lib, the only one who found a way to really solve the problem! But it's buggy when an animation stops (for example display:none), and then running again. It shoul use `animationcancel` too, for observing for stop animation (e.g. `display:none`)

Comment: Sounds like a useful pull request ;)

Answer (score 4):

Calculate and add a delay before adding the class:

```
function getTime (seconds) {
  const msDuration = (seconds * 1000).toFixed(0);
  const currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  const msDelay = msDuration - (currentTime % msDuration);
  return (msDelay / 1000).toFixed(4);
}

$('div').css({animationDelay: getTime(0.6) + "s"}).addClass('animating');
```

https://codepen.io/s-flhti/pen/GRoVXZw

Comment: neat little trick you've got here. I used this one successfully

Answer (score 4):

This was my little quest in synchronizing animations for different elements and [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations), thanks to the ideas above, the solution turned out to be very simple. I hope this small code helps someone.

```
window.addEventListener('animationstart', e =>
    e.animationName == 'rgb' && e.target.getAnimations({subtree: true}).forEach(e => e.startTime = 0), true)
```

Comment: This is super helpful. It's technically still an experimental API but seems to have been supported in all major browsers for years.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can just stack two of the yellow ones and switch visibility on :hover through a parent element.

You need the animation to always be running otherwise you'll run into the sync issue you've got.

I modified your code a bit to get [this.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/phuaH)

Comment: This is very similar to @Valerij solution but I think the former is cleaner because instead of using duplicated content it's using the parent to trigger the bouncing changing position on hover. Take a look: jsfiddle.net/A92pU/2 (you can find it in the OP)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `setInterval` to maintain the animation state of the first animation and give the other animation a negative delay to seek to its matching keyframe on mouse-over.

Read about the state-maintaining-interval-thing [here](http://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/), at the "Manipulating CSS Animations" section; read about the negative delay to seek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110759/seek-to-specific-keyframe-in-css3-animation).

Answer (score 1):

on mouse hover:

1. remove animation classes from both elements
2. use `requestAnimationFrame(() => { ... add here "bounce" class to both elements })`

Should sync nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class on the root element which set the altertating state, and then alternate the class using a timer

CSS

```css
.alt .bouncy {
   padding-top:5px !important;
}
.bouncy {
   padding-top: 1px;
   transition: padding-top ease 500ms;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bouncy">Drip</div>
    <div class="bouncy">droP</div>
<div>
```

Javascript

```js
$(function () {
  setInterval(() => $(".container").toggleClass("alt"), 1000)
})
```

In this way transition and timer do the work of css animation, but controlled by a single master switch (the container).

Answer (score 0):

With [css animation sync lib](https://github.com/bealearts/css-animation-sync) by bealearts, you can easly synchonize animations. But in version 0.4.1 (lastest today), it had the bugs:

1. Sync gets lost, when all the sync-animation elements are stopped they animation (for example `display:none` )
2. First animation starts from non-zero frame after restarting, that may be critical.
3. Some time after the start of the first animation, it flashes.
4. Not working with pseudo-elements `:before`, `:after`

To fix all theese bugs (but 4) , you can fix library code:

-Add animation-cancel callback

```
function animationCancel(event) {
    if (shouldSync(event)) {
      elements.delete(event.target);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('animationcancel', animationCancel, true);
```

-Modify animation-start callback to process first animation

```
function animationStart(event) {
    if (shouldSync(event)) {
      const { target: element, timeStamp } = event;
      elements.add(element);

      let diff;
      if (elements.size == 1){
        diff = 0;
        lastIterationTimestamp = timeStamp;
      }else diff = timeStamp - lastIterationTimestamp;

      element.style.setProperty('animation-delay', `-${diff}ms`);
    }
}
```

-And empty the body of `init()` method.

Here is the fixed using sample:

```js
//Sample demo code
jQuery(function($){
  window.cssAnimationSync('pulse-visible');
  let animateGroup = function(selector){
    let hideNext = function(){
      let next = $(selector + ':visible:first');
      if (next.length){
          next.fadeOut();
          setTimeout(hideNext, 200 + Math.random()*200);
       }else setTimeout(showNext, 200 + Math.random()*200);
    }
    let showNext = function(){
       let next = $(selector + ':hidden:first');
       if (next.length){
          next.fadeIn();
          setTimeout(showNext, 200 + Math.random()*200);
       }else setTimeout(hideNext, 200 + Math.random()*200);
    };
    showNext();
  };
  animateGroup('.pulsar_sync');
  animateGroup('.pulsar');
});


//Fixed library code
/** @see https://github.com/bealearts/css-animation-sync */
window.cssAnimationSync = function(animationNameOrNames) {
  const animationNames = new Set(
    Array.isArray(animationNameOrNames) ? animationNameOrNames : [animationNameOrNames]
  );
  const elements = new Set();
  let animationDuration;
  let isPaused = false;
  let lastIterationTimestamp = 0;

  const api = {
    getElements() {
      return elements;
    },

    free() {
      window.removeEventListener('animationiteration', animationIteration, true);
      window.removeEventListener('animationstart', animationStart, true);

      this.start();
      elements.clear();
    },

    start() {
      elements.forEach((el) => {
        if (validate(el)) {
          if (isPaused) {
            el.style.removeProperty('animation-play-state');
          } else {
            el.style.removeProperty('animation');
          }
        }
      });
      isPaused = false;
    },

    stop() {
      isPaused = false;
      elements.forEach((el) => {
        if (validate(el)) {
          el.style.setProperty('animation', 'none');
        }
      });
    },

    pause() {
      isPaused = true;
      elements.forEach((el) => {
        if (validate(el)) {
          el.style.setProperty('animation-play-state', 'paused');
        }
      });
    }
  };

  function shouldSync(event) {
    return animationNames.has(event.animationName);
  }

  function validate(el) {
    const isValid = document.body.contains(el);
    if (!isValid) {
      elements.delete(el);
    }
    return isValid;
  }

  function init() {
    //setTimeout(restart, animationDuration);
  }

  function restart() {
    api.stop();
    setTimeout(api.start, 50);
  }

  function animationStart(event) {
    if (shouldSync(event)) {
      const { target: element, timeStamp } = event;
      elements.add(element);

      let diff;
      if (elements.size == 1){
        diff = 0;
        lastIterationTimestamp = timeStamp;
      }else diff = timeStamp - lastIterationTimestamp;

      element.style.setProperty('animation-delay', `-${diff}ms`);
    }
  }
  
  function cssToMs(time) {
      const num = parseFloat(time);
      let unit = time.match(/m?s/);

      if (!unit) return 0;

      [unit] = unit;

      switch (unit) {
        case 's':
          return num * 1000;
        case 'ms':
          return num;
        default:
          return 0;
      }
   }


  function animationIteration(event) {
    if (shouldSync(event)) {
      const { target: element, timeStamp } = event;
      elements.add(element);

      lastIterationTimestamp = timeStamp;
      if (!animationDuration) {
        animationDuration = cssToMs(window.getComputedStyle(element).animationDuration);
        init();
      }
    }
  }

  function animationCancel(event) {
    if (shouldSync(event)) {
      elements.delete(event.target);
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('animationiteration', animationIteration, true);
  window.addEventListener('animationstart', animationStart, true);
  window.addEventListener('animationcancel', animationCancel, true);

  return api;
};
```

```css
@keyframes pulse-visible {
    0% { opacity: 0.85;}
    30% { opacity: 0.85;}
    40% { opacity: 0.55;}
    45% { opacity: 0;}
    85% { opacity: 0;}
    90% { opacity: 0.55;}
    100% { opacity: 0.85;}
}

@keyframes pulse-visible-copy {
    0% { opacity: 0.85;}
    30% { opacity: 0.85;}
    40% { opacity: 0.55;}
    45% { opacity: 0;}
    85% { opacity: 0;}
    90% { opacity: 0.55;}
    100% { opacity: 0.85;}
}
.pulsar
{
 animation-name: pulse-visible-copy;
}
.pulsar_sync
{
 animation-name: pulse-visible;
}
.pulsar, .pulsar_sync
{
 animation-duration: 0.7s;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 
 /*styles not depending on animation*/
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 margin: 5px;
 border: 3px solid red;
 border-radius: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
With cssAnimationSync
<div style='min-height:50px;'>
<div class="pulsar_sync" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar_sync" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar_sync" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar_sync" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar_sync" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
Without
<div>
<div class="pulsar" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="pulsar" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```