# Seek to specific keyframe in css3 animation

Tags: css

I am doing a pretty long keyframe css3 animation and I would like to be able to **seek to** a specific keyframe - hence display it - and then play the animation from there.
The animation play/pause/reverse run great.

Here is what I have so far. I can start/pause, reverse but no seek-to avail...

### CSS

```
.myStyle{
    -webkit-animation-name: myStyle-keyframes;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 50000ms;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myStyle-keyframes {
    0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(0px) translateY(0px);}
    0.1% {-webkit-transform:translateX(1.86px) translateY(-0.62px);}
    ...
    100% {-webkit-transform:translateX(182px) translateY(-123px);}
}
```

### JS

`document.getElementById('ball').style.webkitAnimationPlayState='paused';`

OR

`document.getElementById('ball').style.webkitAnimationPlayState='running';`

### HTML

```
<svg id="ball" class="myStyle">[...]</svg>
```

Comment: take a look my implementation in JS, keyframes can be dynamic, also seek works really nice and correct.
preview - https://serg94.github.io/CssAnimationPlayer/index.html
sources - github.com/serg94/CssAnimationPlayer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can seek to a specific keyframe by using a negative animation-delay value.

Comment: great catch! I can still see it there: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/. Isn't this the official spec?

Comment: Ah, I think I was mixing it up with animation duration, sorry. edited the answer to remove that.

Comment: [As reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-delay-property): 
`If the value for ‘animation-delay’ is a negative time offset then the animation will execute the moment it is applied, but will appear to have begun execution at the specified offset. That is, the animation will appear to begin part-way through its play cycle. In the case where an animation has implied starting values and a negative ‘animation-delay’, the starting values are taken from the moment the animation is applied.`

Comment: Ahhh, even after using negative margins a hundred times, this didn't come to my mind :)

Comment: This is my execution. Please preview https://github.com/serg94/CssAnimationPlayer