# Connecting carousel within a carousel using bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please forgive me if this is worded terribly, but I'll do my best. Using Bootstrap 3, I have a large carousel that successfully works with the indicators. However, I also want to add a sort of sidebar that updates to show all slides that are not currently set to `active`. Upon clicking on any of these sidebar tabs, the `active` slide is updated, as well as the sidebar tabs with the newly `inactive` slide.

[image]

Will change into the layout below, upon clicking on either of the elements associated with slide 3...

[image]

At the moment, clicking on either of the elements updates the `active` slide as well as the indicator, but the sidebar tab list remains the same.

Is there a simple way using jQuery and the `data-*` attributes to slide the tab list to only show `inactive` elements?

The only similar solution I came across [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710222/bootstrap-carousel-how-to-slide-two-carousel-sliders-at-a-same-time)

**[Some code](http://www.bootply.com/obALcy6DES)**

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="container carousel-wrap">
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators breadcrumbs">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <ol class="carousel-indicators tabs">
      <li class="small orange" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li class="small red" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li class="small blue" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li class="small purple" data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="jumbotron carousel orange" data-slide-to="0"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="jumbotron carousel red" data-slide-to="1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="jumbotron carousel blue" data-slide-to="2"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="jumbotron carousel purple" data-slide-to="3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```