# css Synchronise keyframe animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyframe

I'm looking to synchronise the keyframe animation of three different elements.

They are basically three hearts and I want them to follow a heartbeat animation when they are clicked.

When two or more are clicked, I want them to "beat" in sync.

You can check a JSbin [here](http://jsbin.com/waruqaneji/1/edit?html,css,output)

What I have so far is :

```css
.rating {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

.rating:not(:checked)>input {
  display: none;
}


/* - - - - - LIKE */

#like {
  bottom: -65px;
}

#like:not(:checked)>label {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 7.5px;
  color: rgba(233, 54, 40, .4);
  line-height: 42px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.2s;
}

#like:not(:checked)>label:hover,
#like:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  color: rgba(233, 54, 40, .6);
}

#like>input:checked+label:hover,
#like>input:checked+label:hover~label,
#like>input:checked~label:hover,
#like>input:checked~label:hover~label,
#like>label:hover~input:checked~label {
  color: rgb(233, 54, 40);
}

#like>input:checked~label {
  color: rgb(233, 54, 40);
  animation: 1s heartbeat infinite;
}

@keyframes heartbeat {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  15% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="like" class="rating">

  <!-- THIRD HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_3" name="like" value="3" />
  <label for="heart_3" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>

  <!-- SECOND HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_2" name="like" value="2" />
  <label for="heart_2" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>

  <!-- FIRST HEART -->
  <input type="radio" id="heart_1" name="like" value="1" />
  <label for="heart_1" class="heart-slider">&#9829;</label>

</section>
```

What is the good way to achieve sync ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Following Rounin's answer, here's the updated CSS that gets the job done :

```
#like {
}
#like:not(:checked) > label {
  cursor:pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;

  color: (255, 255, 255);

  transition: color 0.2s;
}

#like:not(:checked) > label:hover,
#like:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label {
  color: rgba(252, 108, 133, 1);
}
#like > input:checked + label:hover,
#like > input:checked + label:hover ~ label,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover,
#like > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label,
#like > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label {
 color: rgb(252, 108, 133);

}
#like > input:checked ~ label {
  color: rgb(252, 108, 133);

}

#heart_1:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat1 1s infinite;
}

#heart_2:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat2 1s infinite;
}

#heart_3:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat3 1s infinite;
}


@keyframes heartbeat1 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  15% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat2 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  15% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat3 {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  15% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(1.15);
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  35% {
    transform: scale(1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Sync CSS Animations Across Multiple Elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838972/how-to-sync-css-animations-across-multiple-elements)

Comment: Why don't you prepare 3 lines for each kind of rating, e.g., 1 heart, 2 hearts, and 3 hearts? Then you can switch them using checkboxes.

Comment: Hi @gyre, just tried the "bouncywrap" technique from your link but the hearts are now bumping even if not checked. Plus the position: relative seems to mess up with the alignemnent of the hearts.

Comment: @Anson, could you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up 3 identical animations and style your inputs and labels such that when a new radio button is selected, the old animation stops and the new one begins. That way the hearts will always be in sync:

**Working Example:**

```css
div {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 125px;
height: 60px;
box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.4);
}

input {
display: none;
}

label {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
top: 0;
font-size: 40px;
line-height: 60px;
color: rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.75);
}


label:hover,
label:hover ~ label {
color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.like1 {
left: 10px;
}

.like2 {
left: 50px;
}

.like3 {
left: 90px;
}

#like1:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat1 0.8s infinite;
}

#like2:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat2 0.8s infinite;
}

#like3:checked ~ label {
animation: heartbeat3 0.8s infinite;
}

@keyframes heartbeat1 {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  50% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat2 {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  50% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat3 {
  0% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }

  50% {
    color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<input type="radio" id="like3" name="likes" value="3" />
<label class="like3" for="like3">&#9829;</label>

<input type="radio" id="like2" name="likes" value="2" />
<label class="like2" for="like2">&#9829;</label>

<input type="radio" id="like1" name="likes" value="1" />
<label class="like1" for="like1">&#9829;</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. You've made some changes that I did not want so I only kept what I was missing and added it to my original post.

Comment: You're welcome @mattvent - I didn't use exactly the same markup and styling because I was setting out to show you an approach, rather than "do your homework" for you. :D

Comment: Sounds fair ! Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

Modified @Rounin's answer to give you the output you require.

```css
div {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 125px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.4);
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.75);
}

label:hover,
label:hover~label {
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.like1 {
  left: 10px;
}

.like2 {
  left: 50px;
}

.like3 {
  left: 90px;
}

#like1:checked~label {
  animation: heartbeat1 0.8s infinite;
}

#like2:checked~label {
  animation: heartbeat2 0.8s infinite;
}

#like3:checked~label {
  animation: heartbeat3 0.8s infinite;
}

@keyframes heartbeat1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
}

@keyframes heartbeat3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale( 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale( .75);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="like3" name="likes" value="3" />
  <label class="like3" for="like3">&#9829;</label>

  <input type="radio" id="like2" name="likes" value="2" />
  <label class="like2" for="like2">&#9829;</label>

  <input type="radio" id="like1" name="likes" value="1" />
  <label class="like1" for="like1">&#9829;</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Seriously? You don't feel this is plagiarism in any sense, then?

Comment: I did gave you the compliments for it. You're very welcome to update the animation where you should've provided with the solution. :)