# Triggering synced CSS animations with Javascript by setting a timeStabilizer function

Tags: javascript, css, animation, events, time

I want to trigger a simple blinking animation for the following buttons such as.

```html
<style>
@keyframes buttonBlink {
    0% { opacity: 0;}
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
button {
   border-radius: 25%;
   animation: buttonBlink 1s steps(2, start) infinite running;
}
.pressed {
  background-color: lightblue;
  outline: solid 2px black;
}

</style>
<body>
<div>
  <button id="button1" class="">button 1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="">button 2</button>
  <button id="button3" class="">button 3</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( i => {
        i.addEventListener('click', () => {
            i.classList.toggle('pressed');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is that when pressed any button, they will start blinking at their own phase (they will not be in sync). So for that, I have refined the a little bit the expression by adding a function that calculates the difference to the second split in what I called `timeStabilizer()` (in this case `secondStabilizer()`)

```
// function: secondStabilizer . It will execute the executeFunction delayed to
// the next second split

function secondStabilizer(executeFunction) {
    let initTime = new Date();
    initTime = initTime.getTime();
    nextSplitSecond = function nextSplitSecond(inputTimeSign) { 
        return (Math.ceil(inputTimeSign/1000) * 1000);
    }
    delayNeeded = nextSplitSecond(initTime) - initTime;
    setTimeout(executeFunction , delayNeeded);
}
// eof eof eof eof secondStabilizer eof eof eof eof eof
```

The function works when passing simple console.log functions as an argument, but embedding with the code for the toggle of the CSS class, it won't work

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( i => {
    i.addEventListener('click', secondStabilizer( () => {
         i.classList.toggle('pressed');
    }));
});
```

Is the approach good?
Why is not working in my case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838972/how-to-sync-css-animations-across-multiple-elements

Comment: Try putting your js inside a `document.onReadyState` so that the browser will wait for the page to finish loading before attempting any rendering changes from the css.