# Sync the animation of all animated select elements

Tags: html, css

I want the blinking of different select elements to be synchronised. How to achieve this?

```css
select[data-chosen] {
  outline-offset:2px;
  outline:12px solid;
}
select[data-chosen='green'] {
  outline-color: green;
}
select[data-chosen='red'] {
  outline-color: red;
}
select[data-chosen='grey'] {
  outline-color: grey;
}
select[data-chosen='blinkgreen'] {
  outline-color: green;
  animation: blink 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
select[data-chosen='blinkred'] {
  outline-color: red;
  animation: blink 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  100% {
    outline-offset: 2px;
    outline: 12px solid;
    outline-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFE0" style="padding:20px;">
  <select onchange=" this.dataset.chosen = this.value; ">
    <option value="blinkgreen">Running (Fine)</option>
    <option value="blinkred">Running (Issues)</option>
    <option value="green">Completed (Fine)</option>
    <option value="red">Completed (Issues)</option>
    <option value="grey">Yet to start</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFE0" style="padding:20px;">
  <select onchange=" this.dataset.chosen = this.value; ">
    <option value="blinkgreen">Running (Fine)</option>
    <option value="blinkred">Running (Issues)</option>
    <option value="green">Completed (Fine)</option>
    <option value="red">Completed (Issues)</option>
    <option value="grey">Yet to start</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Need a lil bit of help to adjust to my needs. thanks

Comment: For your case I feel the best is to use a constant origin instead of retrieving the one of a potential running animation. I did update [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69612018/2518285) there to include that solution too. And [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyxg3ept/) with your markup.